# Inclusion of Angular directive files into index.html prevents running of one directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I included two simple directives to my index Html file. But weirdly the file I included above is not working.

If I add the files to index.html individually, each file is working well.

My index Html file:

```
<script src="app/directives/spinnerHide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app/directives/moreInformation.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
```

In above case, spinnerHide is not working.

My directives:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app.directives', []);
    app.directive('spHide', spHide);

    function spHide($rootScope) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: linker
        };
        return directive;

        function linker($scope, elm, attrs) {
            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return $rootScope.spinnerActive;
            }, function () {
                if ($rootScope.spinnerActive) {
                    elm.removeClass('ng-hide');
                }
                else {
                    elm.addClass('ng-hide');
                }
            }, true);
         }
      }
    })();


(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app.directives', []);
    app.directive('moreInformation', moreInformation);

    moreInformation.$inject = [];

    function moreInformation() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: linker
        };
        return directive;

        function linker($scope, elm, attrs) {

            $(elm).click(function () {
                var contentObj = $(elm).parents().eq(2).children().eq(1);
                var classNameArr = contentObj.attr('class').split(' ');
                angular.forEach(classNameArr, function (value) {
                    if (value === 'ng-hide') {
                        contentObj.removeClass('ng-hide');
                        contentObj.slideDown();
                        $(elm).children().removeClass('fa fa-chevron-down');
                        $(elm).children().addClass('fa fa-chevron-up');
                     }
                    else {
                        contentObj.slideUp();
                        contentObj.addClass('ng-hide');
                        $(elm).children().removeClass('fa fa-chevron-up');
                        $(elm).children().addClass('fa fa-chevron-down');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

My app.js file:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngStorage',
    'app.auth',
    'angular-confirm',
    'angular-spinkit',
    'datatables',
    'toastr',
    'app.directives'
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your module twice:

```
// Passing a second parameter is declaring the module
var app = angular.module('app.directives', []);
```

You can only declare it once, then use it without the second parameter

```
// Get the module
var app = angular.module('app.directives');
```